# Using Both a Column and an Aggregate Result Set to Join Two Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions

Oracle Beginner here trying to return the highest-paid employee from each store. Is it possible to return this result by executing an `INNER JOIN` ON `MAX`/`SAL+COMM` expressions and a second column (`store_id`), similar in format to the first query below (two-column join)? The Alternative Solution returns the results I want but based solely on total pay, allowing for extraneous results in a larger data set.

```
ENAME   SAL     COMM    STORE_ID
KING    5000    -       3
BLAKE   2850    -       3
CLARK   2450    -       3
JONES   2975    -       1
SCOTT   3000    400     4
FORD    3000    0       4
SMITH   800     700     4

SELECT store_id, ename, (salary+NVL(commission,0)) total_pay 
FROM employees E1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT store_id, MAX(sal+NVL(comm,0)) highest_paid
FROM employees
GROUP BY store_id) E2
ON E1.store_id = E2.store_id
AND total_pay = highest_paid
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE (SAL+NVL(COMM,0)) IN (SELECT MAX(SAL+NVL(COMM,0))
                            FROM EMPLOYEES
                            GROUP BY store_id)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.   "Join the two queries together" doesn't really mean anything.  And what is the `agg` function?  It looks like a column alias on an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but a very natural way to express this logic uses window functions:

```
SELECT storeid, empname, agg
FROM (SELECT e.*, (salary+ COALESCE(commission, 0)) AS agg,
             MAX(salary + COALESCE(commission, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY storeid) as max_agg 
      FROM table.employees e
     ) e
WHERE agg = max_agg;
```